# How to retrive date and time from database and create notification on that particular date

Tags: android

I want to create Reminder.I am using below code to generate notification at a particular time and date set by the user.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TimePicker timePicker;
DatePicker datePicker;
Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
                datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);    
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);     

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();     


                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());                 
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                Intent inn = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlaramDetail.class);
                PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getBaseContext(), 0,inn, 0);       
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);



        }
    });

}
}
```

Below is AlaramDetail class that have code for genrating notification.

```
public class AlaramDetail extends Activity {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more, "This is important notification",System.currentTimeMillis());
    String title = "pay attention";
    String detail = "this is implortant";
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlaramDetail.this,AlaramDetail.class);
    finish();
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AlaramDetail.this, 0,intent ,0 );

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(AlaramDetail.this, title, detail, pintent);

    notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    nm.notify(1, notification);
}   

}
```

above code is working correctly. 
After doing this I have created a database that store multiple date and time inputted by the user.database store date and time as string.now i want to generate notification at particular date and time stored in database.I dont know how to pass date and time from database to calendar.set(int field,int value) commands.I think i can use cursor for retrieving date and time but i dont know what value to pass in where and where args.My database has three columns name,date,time.

Answer (score 1):

Also better to do with storing Time in milliseconds as long in database...it will give you better performance...

After Retrieving data you just set time using this code

```
   Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
   calender.setTimeInMillis(TimeInMilli);
```